# Laravel: Pull data from multiple tables

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel but I dont think Im writing optimised code. I am looking at getting all overdue invoices separated by clients. Invoices table and clients table. client_id is within the invoices table. I have the following below but I wanted to know if there is a better way. I would also want to grab the client name from the clients table. I have created an array so I can loop throgh accordingly on the view file, but again im not sure this is the correct way?:

```
$overdueClients = Invoice::where("date_paid",'0000-00-00')->where("date_due","<=",date("Y-m-d"))->pluck('client_id');
foreach($overdueClients as $overdueClient)
{
    $invoices = Invoice::select("title","total","on_account","date","date_due")->where("date_paid",'0000-00-00')->where("date_due","<=",date("Y-m-d"))->where('client_id',$overdueClient)->get();
    $return[$overdueClient][] = $invoices;
}
return $return;
```

Comment: Why you're doing same thing again, first you're selecting client ids and then you loop them and again you make an array of that id. you can make it by single query. `$return = Invoice::where("date_paid",'0000-00-00')->where("date_due","<=",date("Y-m-d"))->get();`

Comment: Another issue is `get()` use `first()`

Comment: Dilip: I was doing this becuase I want the return array structured that I first loop through clients and place in a container on the view and then internal loop through the invoices. Purely for a aesthetics

Answer (score 0):

yes luckily there is a better way for which term is called `relations` and can use eager loading so what you can do is to make relation is models first :
so in you `Invoice` model you write something like below :

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App/Users');
}
```

you should fix the above relation according to the name and path of your model and in your users model :

```
public function invoices(){
    return $this->hasmany('App/Invoices');
}
```

so now an invoice belongs to a user and a `user` can Have many Invoices . and when you need to get the users which has invoices and overdue invoices you do like below :

```
$users = Invoices::with('users')->where("date_paid",'0000-00-00')->where("date_due","<=",date("Y-m-d"));
```

this is the better way to act because of preventing n+1 problems this way you only load users if they have overdue invoices if not they are not being loaded at all take a look at documentation below :

```
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#introduction
```

i strongly recommand to take time and read this and practice it as you would need it more that you think when you want to work with laravel . hope this helps

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for your help. Ill update my code now

Comment: consider accepting this answer as done if it helped and upvote it please thanks

Comment: I have actually just tried this but I dont think Im getting the correct result. I ran the above it it only showing the invoices in the sql query: 

Invoice::with('clients')->where("date_paid",'0000-00-00')->where("date_due","<=",date("Y-m-d"))->toSql();       shows the following sql "select * from `invoices` where `date_paid` = ? and `date_due` <= ?"

Comment: please change the `toSql()` to `get()` and read about the query builder taking verbs

Comment: forgive me if im looking in the wrong section but I dd(theResult) and look down at anything meaningful:

#relations: array:1 [▼
        "clients" => null
      ]